# Phrasal verb "sort out" used in a different way?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

So, I was reading an article, and just saw this sentence here:

*I figured I'd sort out the train into the city instead of hopping in a cab.*

Is that a common usage of "sort out"? It seems like it would mean "search for" or something like that, but I've never seen it used in this way. I checked in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/sort-out_1#sort-out_1__7) and I think it may fit into definition 3 or 5, but it still sounds weird to me.

Comment: I see @EdwinAshworth, that makes more sense, though it's kinda funny to see a phrasal verb doubling up in meaning like that. I've seen sort out mainly used in the way of 'figuring out' or 'organizing' (definitions 1 and 2), but your explanation makes sense and stays true to the dictionary meaning of the phrasal verb.

Comment: [Augmented; largely prior to comment/response above] I'll probably not find a subsense in a dictionary backing this up, but I've always taken this as meaning 'find the necessary information **and** make the necessary arrangements [to facilitate the operation involved]'. Macmillan senses 3 & 4. The DO (dancing, music, train, transport ...) _may_ be predictable, but (as with 'train', 'buses') may be metonymic ('train' = 'transport using a train/trains').

Answer (score 2):

**sort out** (v.)

> Arrange or organize something
>
> *They are anxious to sort out travelling arrangements*
>
> *I've sorted the travel - that's no problem.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sort_out)

---

> He stood beside her as she **sorted out** the ticket, then they walked
> across the car park together, almost amused. [Ann Enright; *A Green
> Road*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Green_Road_A_Novel/8AmdBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sorted%20out%20the%20ticket%22&pg=PT183&printsec=frontcover)

> From the Job Centre, we went straight to the train station to **sort
> out** the train times. [Richard Cliff; *Franklyn*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Franklyn/ohRDCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sort%20out%20the%20train%22&pg=PT56&printsec=frontcover)

> I have **sorted out** the train tickets to get the cast up to Edinburgh
> on Monday. [Robert Bryndza; *The Not So Secret Email of Coco Pinchard*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Not_So_Secret_Emails_of_Coco_Pinchar/3UA3DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sorted%20out%20the%20train%22&pg=PT237&printsec=frontcover)

> Roger had **sorted out** the travel arrangements with S.E.L. but
> coordinating everything else was delegated to Ian. [Andy Gee; *Livin' the
> Dream*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Livin_the_Dream/osxHEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sorted%20out%20the%20travel%22&pg=PT223&printsec=frontcover)

> The Firm had **sorted out** the plane ticket for Mark and, here he
> was, bright and early, at Heathrow airport, waiting to fly British
> Airways to Frankfurt; from Frankfurt, a Lufthansa flight would take
> him to Tehran. [James Brandon; *Zahedan*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Zahedan/qMe2KJeTp80C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sorted%20out%20the%20plane%22&pg=PT52&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

From [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sort-out):

Sort out:

> 4. (especially British English) to succeed in making arrangements for something.